# Detect featured image among the attached images

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I use the following code to extract the attached images from a post with ID:

```
$args            =   array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $product_id,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'numberposts'    => -1
);

$attachments     =   get_posts($args);
```

The problem is that the above code return all the attached files. Is there a way to remove from the results the featured image ? I don't mind if I will do it through the $args query, by some if statement or by filtering the $attachments array.

Kind regards
Merianos Nikos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add an `post__not_in` argument and use the `get_post_thumbnail_id()` function.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $product_id,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post__not_in'   => array(get_post_thumbnail_id($product_id))
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this after your above code.

```
foreach( $attachments as $key => $attachment ) {
    if ( $attachment->ID == get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ) ) {
        unset ( $attachments[$key] );
        break;
    }
}
```

Now `$attachments` would contain all the attachments of `$product_id` except the featured image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

basicaly what you want is this

```
<?php  
//get post thumbnail url  
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url($post_thumbnail_id);  
//get your attachments. <- your query
//now loop your attachments <- foreach or something

 if($attachment->ID != $post_thumbnail_id)
    {
//if the attachment id is the same as your post_thumbnail_id it means you are looking at your feature image
    }
```